# Block Device driver read/write from user application

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I am trying to implement "simple file-system" for my personal experience. For this, I have created a block device driver with which I will perform read/write operations in unit of blocks. Now my question is how should I perform **open, read, write and close** operation on the block device from the user application.

What I am actually looking for is a function with which I can open the block device **/dev/sbd** and it returns the `struct block_device`, if successful. And for the read/write functions, I can issue request to block device `struct request` with parameters as "buffer, sectore_number, numbe_of_sectors".

Till now I only got `block_read()` and `block_write()` functions. But it seems that they are BSD specific. And I am using Debain.

Anyone having idea about it? 
Thanks.

Comment: A device driver is handled by the kernel which a user application never has direct access to.

Comment: yes, but after loading the device driver in the kernel, a user is allowed to perform the read/write operation on the file/device created by the driver.

Comment: True, but the way the question was written doesn't specify that.  Furthermore, he does not specify if this is user mode or kernel mode code that he is writing, so I have to assume user mode.

Comment: In first paragraph, I have mentioned that I have written the device driver and I am looking for functions to perform operations on that device. And it is user mode.

Comment: Your block device driver has open/read/write/close entry points, right?  What is preventing from you from using `int fd = open ("/dev/sbd", 0); read (fd, buf, sizeof buf)`?

Comment: @wallyk : `read (fd, buf, sizeof buf)` uses internal `vfs_read()` and I'm trying to implement my own file-system. And with this function I can't perform the specific sector read as I mentioned in second para, last line.

Comment: This might be a bit of a detour, but do you know about [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Thanks @wallyk. I will look into it. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing something similar writing a application level file system that works with files or devices.  What you are writing is not really a device driver as device drivers are directly handled/used by the kernel.  A user application has no way to access one directly.  Regardless, I want to point you to the function calls open(2), read(2), write(2), close(2) (manual page section 2 for all of them).  You will need the unistd.h header file to use these.  You can set your read/write size as a multiple of your block size when calling read and write.  But in the end, you are still going through the kernel.

EDIT: Upon further examination and comments, the device driver really is in the kernel.  Normally, there is no direct connection between a driver and an application as there are several layers of code within the kernel to abstract the device so it looks the same like everything else to the application.

There are two ways around this.  One is to establish one or more system calls in the system call tree to expose the read/write routines of the device driver to the application.  Another idea that I had was to use the ioctl (I/O Control) system call to perform this, but this call is meant to control the actual device.  For example, the hard disk uses read and write commands to transfer data, but to talk to the hard drive to get information about it, such as what the last LBA is or get its identity, you would use IOCTL to do that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already written the device driver. i am looking a way to access that device from user application. These function calls open(2), read(2), write(2), close(2) are of no use as they use vfs calls inside.

Comment: Is the device driver in the kernel or the application?  Just saw the comment on the original question.  Since the code is usermode, you have no choice in the matter.  You have to use those calls to open, read/write, and close the file/device that you are working with.

Comment: You can't have it to be both user mode and kernel mode.  It's one or the other.  If your device driver really is in the kernel, you can establish a series of system calls to allow an application to directly access it then.  There is an ioctl system call, but those are device specific and I don't know much about them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I have a block device driver in kernel. And I have another user application (simple file-system application) in user mode, which will open the block device and perform read/ write operation.

Comment: I did thought about system call, but later I found out that its quite a complicated procedure as I would be requiring to recompile my kernel for that. So I drop that option.

Comment: I've added syscalls to kernels with KLM before.  All you do is load the address of the entry point into the appropriate vector.  Make sure to save the previous one first so when you unload the KLM, it can restore it.